# I dont understand equation/identity holds true

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a$ be a solution to $x^2-x-1=0$.
Consider $\frac{x}{a-1}$; if we expand this we get
$$\frac{x}{a-1}=\frac{2 x}{-1 + \sqrt5}$$ or
$$\frac{x}{a-1}=\frac{-2 x}{1 + \sqrt5}$$

If we solve the equation $ax=\frac{x}{a-1}$, we get $a^2-a-1=0$, so $ax$ should be equal to $\frac{x}{a-1}$. But if I try to evaluate $ax$, I get $$-\frac{-1 + \sqrt5x}{2}$$ or $$\frac{1 + \sqrt5x}{2}.$$
These are obviously not equal to what I got when I evaluated $\frac{x}{a-1}$, so where is the mistake? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: [MathJax, please](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Are they really not equal? Use rationalization/calculator to find out.

Answer (score 1):

We have $a^2-a-1=a(a-1)-1=0$ so since $a\neq0,1$ we have $a-1=\frac{1}{a},$ so $\frac{1}{a-1}=a$ and hence $\frac{x}{a-1}=ax.$

The roots of $a^2-a-1=0$ are $a_{1}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $a_{2}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}.$

So $\frac{x}{a_{1}-1}=\frac{x}{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}-1}=\frac{2x}{-1+\sqrt{5}}=\frac{2x}{-1+\sqrt{5}}\times\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{-1-\sqrt{5}}=\frac{-2x(1+\sqrt{5})}{-4}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}x=a_{1}x$

and similarly you can show that $\frac{x}{a_{2}-1}=a_{2}x.$